# How to write typescript async axios? And how to use try/catch

Tags: typescript, axios

I'm trying to figure out what's the best way to write typescript async axios requests. If Should each function have it's own try/catch block? If yes, how should I type the function result?

With try/catch block, the type is: `Promise<ExpectedType | undefined>`
Without the try/catch block, the type is `Promise<ExpectedType>`

Here is the example:

```
async function v1(): Promise<ExpectedType> {
  const response = await axios.get('https://...')
  return response.data
}

async function v1Copy(): Promise<ExpectedType> {
  const response = await axios.get('https://...')
  return response.data
}

async function v2(): Promise<ExpectedType | undefined> {
  try {
    // I could use object destructuring for 'data' but ignore this for now
    const response = await axios.get('https://...')
    return response.data
  } catch (e) {
    // how to handle this safely
    const error = e as AxiosError | Error
    if (error instanceof AxiosError) {
      if (error.response) {
        console.error(`axios error: ${error.response.status} ${error.response.statusText}`)
      } else {
        console.error(`axios error: ${error.message}`)
      }
    } else {
      console.error(`generic error: ${error.message}`)
    }
  }
}
```

Now, when I need to use `v1 / v1Copy` in another part of my code, I have to wrap it inside a try catch/catch block. This is obvious.

What's the best way to do this?

```
...
try {
  const v1Result = await v1()
  const v1CopyResult = await v1Copy()
  // use v1Result and v1CopyResult
} catch(e) {}
```

vs

```
...
const v2Result = await v2()
if (typeof v2Result !== 'undefined') {
  // here should be a typeguard, right?
  // use v2Result
}
```

It is ok to use `v1` and `v1Copy` inside same try/catch block?
Thanks... I'm trying to find what's the best way to handle this and understand why.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to wrap each function in it's own try/catch block so that the whole code won't blow if a promise gets rejected.